# Animate a div as slide changes

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to create something like the ones present in the first site [site-1][1] and [site-2][2]. Now the thing I want is, div should animate every time the slides on the site i'm working on

```
revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
    //alert("slider loaded");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
    //alert("slide changed to: "+data.slideIndex);
    //data.slideIndex is the index of the li container in this Slider   
    //data.slide is the current slide jQuery object (the li element)    
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onpause",function (e,data) {
    //alert("timer paused");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onresume",function (e,data) {
    //alert("timer resume");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onvideoplay",function (e,data) {
    //alert("video play");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onvideostop",function (e,data) {
    //alert("video stopped");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onstop",function (e,data) {
    //alert("slider stopped");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onbeforeswap",function (e) {
    //alert("before swap");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onafterswap",function (e) {
    //alert("after swap");
});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.slideatend",function (e) {
    //alert("slide at end");
});
```

api for slider i'm using hope it might help

this is how i'm running animation i want the animation to run on each slide

```
revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
        jQuery('#scrollBottom').css('-webkit-animation','bounce 1s 2');

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I'm able to solve my problem here how i restarted the animation after every slide

var scrollbottom= jQuery('#scrollBottom');

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onbeforeswap",function (e) {
scrollbottom.removeClass('bounceanimate').width();

});

revapi2.bind("revolution.slide.onafterswap",function (e) {
  scrollbottom.addClass('bounceanimate');

});

and here is good read from css tricks
[restart css animation](http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/)